# Computer Does Not Work At Home But Works in PC Repair Shop

Tags: motherboard, power-supply, ups

I have never encountered this phenomenon. No, it's not phenomenon - it's anomaly that defies logic.

My computer was left for 1 week in a mixed standby hibernate state. I think it's S4, don't remember. It was plugged in to UPS. When I wanted to wake it up from standby, it didn't. Then I pressed on power button on my case and it made no difference.

Tried testing PSU alone, cooler was spinning. Used multimeter to test voltages and all was within normal range. Sent my under warranty motherboard to PC repair shop, they checked, said it works and updated BIOS as a bonus. Received motherboard back and same thing.

This time I took motherboard, CPU, RAM module and PSU to a local PC repair shop. Yes, that's second PC repair shop! They tested, all was working but when I tried to turn it on at home, again it didnt. Plugged power cable to UPS, disconnected UPS from mains to make sure PSU runs from UPS battery and it didn't work. Tried different power cable, it didn't help. Tried in different rooms but to no avail.

I am going crazy. Nothing makes sense. This is unreal.

CPU: AMD Ryzen 5 3600X

Motherboard: Gigabyte B450 Aorus Elite

RAM: 2x8GB Corsair Vengeance LPX

PSU: Corsair TX650M

Comment: Have you tried bypassing the power-on switch and turning on the system by shorting the power  header pins on the board? Just a basic check to confirm that there's no fault with the button.

Comment: Yes sir. I used paper clip, I used knife, I used screwdriver. Anything else I can use?

Comment: Are you in a country that uses two different mains voltages? (For example, Guyana has 120V on some sockets and 240V on others.) If so, are you using the right power rating for your computer? Is there a 120V/240V switch on the PSU that you might have knocked?

Comment: Aren't you using a Discrete Graphics Card? 3600X does not have a built-in GPU? Was the system at local repair shop tested with your graphics or their's? What if you try running the system with very minimum components at your end? Just CPU, 1 RAM, Board & PSU.

Comment: We have 240V. No voltage switch on PSU. I run the system with CPU, 1 RAM, motherboard and PSU. Nothing happens except led on motherboard turning on for 1 second after I switch on I/0 button on power supply. After I touch power on pins on motherboard, no CPU fan turning, no power supply fan turning. Complete silence. I don't need my discrete graphics card to tell me this.

Comment: Have you made sure that you have nothing else on the MB then what you took to the shop. Even the smallest thing can make a difference. Mouse, keyboard, dongle, monitor? You have tried it with the exact same components that you took to the Shop?

Comment: I just would like to further comment that try to find out what is that difference between your system/your home/UPS and local repair shops. It could be mains/UPS/earthing/static charges/voltages or any other PC components combination, cabinet, possible short etc. Does the board power on without CPU? it should do nothing but you should see the fan connected to CPU fan header or sys fan header running, if it powers on.

Comment: Tried it with exact components except discrete graphics card. They tested with their own discrete graphics card. I tried with my own graphics card and without it. No difference. Tried removing CPU, connected CPU fan to 4-pin CPU socket, connected to SYS_FAN. Nothing worked.

Comment: For another data point - could you try it in a third location? It's unusual :/

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the comments, you did what you could do to emulate what was at the shop. Ideally, you would try to boot the computer with the PC_SPKR plugged in to the motherboard (the one that beeps on a successful bootup), remove all the RAM, and power on to hear 3 beeps (showing the motherboard is likely working).

If the computer appears dead, and the power button / shorting out pins on the motherboard is not helping, then I'd start looking at the Power Supply - both the unit, and the circuit in your home.

Can you bring it to a friend's house to try? If it starts up there, then we proved it's a wiring issue in the home. If it doesn't start up there, then it's more evidence there is something wrong with the computer.

Comment: I am on 1st floor in apartment building. I took PSU, motherboard, CPU and RAM to my neighbor on 3rd floor to test. It still didn't work.

Comment: What about outside of your apartment, to a building that doesn't share the same electrical as you?

Comment: What if you borrow a PSU from the local repair shop, bring it to your place and test it again with that PSU? I know your PSU worked at local shop & also worked in paperclip test in your house but just in case for some reasons if it's not producing enough power due to some other conditions lurking in your house, when rest of the components are connected?

Comment: I will have to try find local repair shop that will borrow me PSU. What if I post on Facebook and find someone who will borrow me PSU?

Comment: @CanadianLuke I used UPS battery to draw power from. Isn't that better than testing outside of my building?

Comment: In short all I meant was to try and use another working PSU.  You can even try to obtain another working PC, at least PSU, CPU, RAM & board and see if it boots in your home. How to obtain it is entirely your choice. Generally since the local repair shop guys know your issue, they might be ready to extend such a help for some fee. Is your UPS having AVR feature? Voltage Regulation?

Comment: @patkim Yes, my UPS has voltage regulation.

Comment: @Boris_yo UPS is not perfect. Trying to go half-way through the path :P

Answer (score 1):

If it's not pure coincidence - which is the most likely explanation - here are some more theories:

- Your UPS is broken - or is outputting a nonstandard voltage that's not working well with your power supply. If you put a signal analyzer or oscilloscope to a power signal, you will see some pretty interesting things, especially on the output of cheap UPSes. **Remedy #1: Don't use the UPS.**
- Your wall power is nonstandard - I'm not sure what country you're in, but I once measured 70V from the wall socket. Needless to say, only random things worked. Other explanations may be electrical noise on your home circuitry. **Remedy #2: Try at a friend's place.**
- Your PSU is damaged. **Remedy #3: Try another PSU**
- It's some sort of software issue. **Remedy #4: Try using Linux for a while and see if it does the same, that eliminates software as the issue.**

Comment: My system can't start. It's not a software issue.

Answer (score 0):

I ordered new power supply and then hoping for a miracle I tried to power on my system again. It powered up. I have no idea what happened but I used paperclip and managed to power it up. I cancelled order of new power supply that same day because I saw that my power supply worked. Then after I plugged in second memory module I received error. The system did not detect it. I unplugged the module and plugged it back and it was detected. Ran Memtest86 with heatsink on CPU without thermal paste applied. Temperature went as high as 93 C so I had to abort the test. Applied thermal paste using "X" method and ran Memtest86 again. This time temperature was stable and after completing the test, it showed that memory was good. Put everything back into the chassis and so far so good. Thanks to all who tried to help me here.